# How to block existing async web requests?

Tags: java, rx-java

I have provided a callback to a third party library that calls the provided method at various times providing me with an object that has changed. I am then carrying out an async web request to get further details and set them on that object, below is a made up similar example;

```
public void update(Person person) {
     if (person.getId() == -1) {
         mService.getPersonDetails()
                 .flatMap(..)
                 .skip(..)
                 .subscribe(personResult -> person.setId(personResult.getId()))
     }
}
```

The update is called quite a few times and should only executes the query if the object has no ID. The problem is that at least two requests get sent off as the first query has not yet completed.

How can I synchronise this method call so that only one request is sent for each Object that get passed via the callback? I only want to block requests for that exact Object, so if the update() is supplying different objects it would be ok for new requests to be sent out.

Comment: Set a flag when the request starts (or before it starts) and clear it when it fails. Check the flag before starting a new request (and make sure it is always cleared on success/fail completion). An IdentityHashMap can be used to manage a flag guard per-instance.

Comment: There might be tidier ways to handle this, possibly with Futures (or other async management) instead of merely flags, but at some level that's the bit that happens - remembering (and checking) what state the action is. The end goal probably shouldn't be to 'block' the call (sounds like a traffic jam!) but to either take-first or take-last (or maintain some combined stated), depending on the desired behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution provided by Adam S looks good but soon or later will cause OOM problems. It is due to distinct operator which has to store all unique values.

Other option that comes to my mind is usage of ConcurrentMap to store processed persons and doOnTerminate to clean it.

```
    private Map<Person, Boolean> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    public void update(final Person person) {
     if (person.getId() == -1) {
        if(map.putIfAbsent(person, true)==null){
           mService.getPersonDetails()
                 .flatMap(..)
                 .skip(..)
                 .doOnTerminate(()->map.remove(person))
                 .subscribe(personResult -> person.setId(personResult.getId()))
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a way to get around the potential OOM issues (up to a point, of course). Yours gets around it altogether though.

Comment: I don't think the above will work? putIfAbsent throws a npe is the key does not exist?

Comment: to work correctly, Person must have equals method implemented. putIfAbsent return true if the element was actually added to the map

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to return the previous value.. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29 . I have got around this by doing a basic containsKey() and put() manually

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the inputs to your observable using the [`distinct`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html) operator. Here's a general idea of how you could do that using a [`PublishSubject`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) ([JavaDoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/PublishSubject.html)) (note this is written from memory, I haven't tested this):

```
private PublishSubject<Person> personSubject;
public void update(Person person) {
     if (personSubject == null) {
         personSubject = new PublishSubject();
         personSubject
            .filter(person -> person.getId() == -1)
            .distinct()
            .flatMap(person -> mService.getPersonDetails())
            .skip(..)
            .subscribe(personResult -> person.setId(personResult.getId()));
     }
     personSubject.onNext(person);
}
```

You will, of course, have to either implement the `equals` method on your `Person` class (which, as Marek points out, will result in all objects passed in being cached in memory) or implement the [`distinct(Func)`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/34cd1a6aa92d6db612147ef5ad79e14bc989b709/src/main/java/rx/Observable.java#L4040) variant.

That method takes a 'key selector' function used to differentiate between objects. If your objects are fairly heavy and you're concerned about memory (if you're on Android, for example) this might be a better path. Something like this:

```
.distinct(new Func1<Person, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer call(Person person) {
                    return person.hashCode();
                }
            })
```

Comment: I've updated this to include the id check in the observable chain `filter(person -> person.getId() == -1)` and a solution to the memory issue pointed out by @Marek which makes it overall much nicer.

Comment: This is a nice solution, memory is going to be critical though. Also the person objects have a limited lifetime, and new Person's could have the same object id.. so I think distinct would block newly create object that have recycled IDs.

Comment: Ah, okay. This would work well for unique IDs during a typical 'sync' operation which gets setup & torn down, but perhaps not for something long-running - and if your ids aren't unique, then keeping a reference _only_ while a request is running is best achieved (I think) through Marek's method.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can just simply `synchronize` it.

```
public synchronized void update(Person person)
```

Comment: Ok. How do you call this method?

Comment: I believe the problem is that the getPersonDetails async.. so update finishes before the request is complete.

Comment: `synchronized` won't work because the problem isn't about threading (the update is [or can be] always invoked on the same thread and result in the same issues)

Comment: @user3032878 You could try what user2864740 suggested by setting flags. I think that should solve your problem.